# What are the chances of getting loot when giving meds to a sick man?

Tags: a-dark-room

Sometimes a sick man hobbles to you and asks for medicine. I used to give it to them, and get loot as reward. But recently nothing happens and just "expresses his thanks" and he go's away. What are the chances of getting loot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [game's code](https://github.com/doublespeakgames/adarkroom/blob/9e3874bc8ee1dffe7625015ab24b5131588a7251/script/events/room.js#L608):

- 50% chance: no loot
- 20% chance: 5 scales
- 20% chance: 3 cells
- 10% chance: 1 alien alloy